# Not Changing to Image Once Loaded (image gallery) - Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I have been working on an image gallery in PHP and Javscript for a long time. The "selling point" of the gallery is that it pre-loads images so when you switch to the next image, you don't have to reload the page *and* it is almost instantaneous.

The problem is that currently when you switch to a photo that has not been loaded, it loads every image before it. I want to load the image that should be currently showed to the viewer. But even when the console says the current image is loaded (console.log messages I set up), it does not switch until all the other photos before it have been loaded.

An [example page](http://goo.gl/srWNG) in question.
I will put some of the most important code here because I don't want to give all the code.

This function **load_image** adds the next photo to be loaded to the hidden_container. The problem is that when the current_photo has loaded, it is not changed. You can test this in the page by viewing the console and using the arrow keys to go all the way to the last photo.

```
    function load_image() {
    // find the next photo to load
    var next_to_load = next_photo_to_load();
    //stop condition:
    if (next_to_load == null)
        return false;

    if (img[current_photo]['loaded'] == 0) {
        console.log("current_photo: "+current_photo);
        next_to_load = current_photo;
        console.log("next_to_load: "+next_to_load)
    }
    else {
        console.log("*current_photo loaded*");
        $("main_img").src = img[current_photo]['img'];
    }

    img[next_to_load]['loaded'] = 1;
    var url = img[next_to_load]['img'];
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function() {
        load_image();
    };

    document.getElementById("hidden_container").appendChild(image);
}
```

Also, load_image is initially called when the first photo is loaded with this code. (I included this because it explains the extra console log).

```
img[current_photo]['loaded'] = 1;
console.log("loaded:"+current_photo);
load_image();
```

Thanks for reading all of this. I know it is long.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I may be reading your code wrong, but at no stage do you set the value of current_photo (apart from the last snippet). All I get in the console when I browse is "*current_photo loaded*" along with "loaded: x" where x is the correct photo to load (I presume).

Comment: @djlumley: No you are not reading the code wrong. By "set the value of current_photo" do you mean setting the main_img src as current_img or do you mean changing loaded status of the current_img?
To see the wrong photo loaded, you can press the right arrow to go all the way to last photo (look in the upper right hand corner) and look in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, I have used this in a mobile gallery I have recently developed.

```
var imageList = $('#imagelist');   //id of div tag
imageList.empty();
var imageFiles = '<?=$images_js?>';
imageFiles = $.parseJSON(imageFiles);  //convert to json for javascript readability

var images = [];
for(i = 0; i<imageFiles.length; i++){
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = imageFiles[i];
    images.push(image);
}

var count = imageFiles.length;
var i = 0;

imageList.append(images[i]);
```

You can see I have used a php variable within the javascript.  I have done this so I can have the php file which is included with this javascript dynamically read the contents of the folder.

the php file is very small and consists of:

```
<?php

$imagesDir = 'gallery/img/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

$images_js = json_encode($images);
?>
```

Here is the jquery in action:

```
$('#contentPlaylist').live('swipeleft swiperight',function(event){

    if (event.type == "swipeleft") {
        imageList.fadeOut('slow', function(){
            imageList.empty();

            if(i != 0){

                i--;
                imageList.append(images[i]);            
                imageList.fadeIn('slow');
            }


            else{
                i = count - 1;
                imageList.append(images[i]);            
                imageList.fadeIn('slow');

            }
        });
    }
    if (event.type == "swiperight") {
            imageList.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                imageList.empty();
                i++;        
                if(i < count){

                    imageList.append(images[i]);            
                    imageList.fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else{

                    imageList.append(images[0]);

                    imageList.fadeIn('slow');
                    var reset = 0;
                    i = reset;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't this load all the images at once? Another specific point about my image gallery was that it loads only one image at time thus allowing you to view the next image faster.

Comment: It loads all at once yes, but you can display the first image immediately after its loaded.  The other images are not displayed until you set a click function to increase or decrease in a loop.  Ill add that code in a moment when I can edit my post.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. It is _imperative_ to the way my gallery works that it only loads one image at a time. My understanding of what you are saying is that it will load the main image, then load all the images at the same time.

Comment: yes, they are loaded but they are not appended until an increase in the loop.
Sorry if this does not help.